# store radio button field in database php and android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have radio button in android application, in registration step 
his name :user_type (student or teatcher)

I want to store `user_type (Student or teacher)` in my database 
I use mysql and php to connect between them

so in `mysql create field name user_type`

and in php, what should I do ?
should I define this field like normal field (Textbox)?
like this

```
 $user_type = $_POST['user_type'];
```

and in query

```
"insert into users (user_type) values ('$user_type')";
```

Comment: you can use varchar or boolean :D

Comment: where i use it ? can you explain it , and is my above code is right ?

Comment: and i just need to store user_type information into database not to check it

Comment: Don't you know about REST API? At first, learn about it.

Answer (score 1):

just get radio button text with getText() and save it in database with text or string format and retrieve it like this:

```
if(user_type.equals("student"){

 }else if (user_type.equals("teacher"){

}
```

Comment: this code i write it in android application or wher?

Comment: this code is example for what you will doing for retrieving your radio button state . not complete code for android